# PUT command on google drive api giving 404 error

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I'm trying to update an already existing file on google drive using curl PUT command, I'm giving the right file ID but still it's showing 404 error.

Following is the curl command I'm using :

```
curl -v -X PUT -L -H "Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>" -F 'file=@<filePath>;type=application/octet-stream' "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/<fileId>?uploadType=multipart"
```

Is there something missing here? User is the file owner itself so permissions are there.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the information on the input and output situations you expect? For example, what is `an already existing file on google drive`? And, what is `file=@<filePath>;type=application/octet-stream`? And, can you provide the detailed information about `but still it's showing 404 error.`? And, your access token can be used for updating the file on Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that the [file.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) method is a PATCH not a GET method

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

Second issue what are you planning on updating? you need to send any changes to the file metadata in the body.

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/xxxxxxxxxx?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{}' \
  --compressed
```

How are you planning on uploading the file itself?  i beleave you need to use the file command.

```
curl -X PATCH -L \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
    -F 'metadata={name :\'%s\'};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
    -F 'file=file.zip;type=application/zip' \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/xxxxxx?uploadType=multipart"
```